# Android - Get max safe stream volume

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I have a use case to change stream volume programmatically, but on newer android volume, raising the volume above a certain limit (60% as per my observations which corresponds to step 9 on most phones) results in a warning dialog:

```
Listening at high volume for a long time may damage your hearing. Tap OK to allow the volume 
to be increased above safe levels
Cancel OK
```

I couldn't find any documentation about this in the the android developer portal, all I could find are some  random articles citing the European regulations like this [one](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-automatically-disable-the-high-volume-warning-without-root/):

```
According to regulations set by the European Committee for Electrotechnical Standarisation (CENELEC), all electronic devices capable of media playback sold after February 2013 must have a default output volume level of a maximum 85 dB. Users can choose to override the warning to increase the volume to a maximum of 100 dB, but in doing so the warning must re-appear after 20 hours of music playback.
```

So I need to figure out reliably what that number is, so I don't ever result in a volume change that would show this dialog, but I also don't want to just use step 9 as the max volume and, then find out that it's not the right value for another phone. Does the android API expose the max safe stream volume anywhere? If not, then do they at least document the step number that corresponds to it for different phone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a resource which holds the safe volume step: `config_safe_media_volume_index`

```
// .../overlay/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml
<integer name="config_safe_media_volume_index">7</integer>
```

It is defined [HERE](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml#2270)

And it is used [HERE](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/audio/AudioService.java)

You can get it dinamically via:

```
int safeVolumeStep;
int safeVolumeStepResourceId = 
       getResources().getIdentifier("config_safe_media_volume_index", "integer", "android");

if(safeVolumeStepResourceId != 0) {
    safeVolumeStep = getResources().getInteger(safeVolumeStepResourceId);
} else {
    Log.w("TESTS", "Resource config_safe_media_volume_index not found. Setting a hardcoded value");
    // We probably won't fall here because config_safe_media_volume_index is defined in the AOSP
    // It not a vendor specific resource...
    // For any case, try to set the safe step manually to 60% of the max volume.
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    safeVolumeStep = (int) (maxVolume * 0.6f);
}

Log.d("TESTS", "Safe Volume Step: " + safeVolumeStep +
               " Safe volume step resourceID: "  + Integer.toHexString(safeVolumeStepResourceId) );
```

I tested here in a Galaxy S10 and I'm getting 9.

Comment: Works perfectly! one thing I noticed is that you need to decrement the value retrieved if you want the maximum safe index. For me on GalaxyS9, the safeVolumeStep is 10 and if I set to that level I get the warning, When I set to 9, I don't get the warning, which matches the documentation:
 
Safe headphone volume index. When music stream volume is below this index the SPL on headphone output is compliant to EN 60950 requirements for portable music players.

Comment: I should also note that while this works for Samsung devices, on the Pixel3 with Android 9 I am getting 3 as the safeVolumeStep, which couldn't possibly be accurate since it has 25 volume steps.